# How to Set Layout Background in Android UI

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android programming.  I have a UI with some `TextView` and `Button` controls.  How do I set a background behind those components?  Lets call it `background.png`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in your parent layout element, e.g. linearlayout or whatever, simply add `android:background="@drawable/background"` This will set the background of your layout, assuming you have the image in a /drawable folder.

Comment: Thanks you. I found this way too : 
linearlyaout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.FILENAME);

Comment: If the image is *NOT* in svg or psd format, the resultant background may of lower quality. How to set a background without losing the quality for all devices?

Comment: @SamudraGanguly see the documentation here https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp for providing assets for each screen density

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. Paste an image in res/drawable-ldpi/ folder for whatever you want to display and in your xml write this:

```
< LinearLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/icon">
< Button/>

< TextView   />

 
< / LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to place your `background.png` image in your `res/drawable/` folder.Later you have to set a parent layout for your `TextView` and `Button` widgets.I will consider a `LinearLayout` as a parent layout for you and the code goes like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@drawable/background.png" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TextView    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="@string/hello" />
 <Button      android:text="Button" 
              android:id="@+id/button1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at : [android:background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground)

This is a sample xml of what you might need to build on ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/my_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:background="@drawable/background">        
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set background color/drawable in xml file or from java file.

1. Changing background in XML file

   [`android:background`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground) is responsible for setting up background in View. 
   So add this if you want to set background to any [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). Eg. in top `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or `TextView` or `Button` etc. Depends on your requirements.

   android:background="@drawable/background"
2. Changing background from Java file

   use [`setBackgroundResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) to set background to any View.

   or simply if you want to change the color of the View you have to use [`setBackgroundColor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

android:background="@drawable/yourBG" in XML.

```
yourLayout.setBackgroundResource(resid);
```

or
    yourLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawble);

Answer (score 0):

first right click on "Drawable" folder in your Project Tab.
select new-> image asset and then select your image.

In your layout coding of xml file, set android:background="@Drawable/background.png"

Answer (score 0):

first copy high resolution image that you want to set in background and then past it(Doing right click on Drawable folder).

then set property of layout as below
android:background="@drawable/Yourimagefilename"

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the background image programmatically this way:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```