# How to add background in grid layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanna add a background image in grid layout.But its not working.My code is below:

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="365dp"
    android:layout_height="365dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="142dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: wrap your grid view inside RelativeLayout and set backgound image for RelativeLayout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How I can I add a background image to a GridLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053727/android-how-i-can-i-add-a-background-image-to-a-gridlayout)

Comment: can you provide some more view related data? what kind of view you're trying to achieve here.. you can also use the recycler view with the GridLayoutManager(activity, 2 // i.e span count)

Comment: I notice you are using ContraintLayout. So you can also create ImageVIew... and align to your GridView.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Set Layout Background in Android UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177688/how-to-set-layout-background-in-android-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `android:background="@drawable/background_from_drawable"` in your code.

'background_from_drawable' is any color or pic